# MySQL Query to display room availability in a range of one week

Tags: mysql

I am developing a system to enable booking of rooms on one hour basis. I have the following tables:
Bookings
Rooms
Slots
Days

Days Table
Contains all days in a year. (Below is just a snapshot of days in June)

```
+-----------+------------+--------------------+
| id        |  date_day  | created_at         |
+-----------+------------+------------+-------+
|         1 | 2017-06-20 |2017-06-26 22:05:11 |
|         2 | 2017-06-21 |2017-06-26 22:05:12 |
|         3 | 2017-06-22 |2017-06-26 22:05:20 |
|         4 | 2017-06-23 |2017-06-26 22:05:24 |
|         5 | 2017-06-24 |2017-06-26 22:05:28 |
|         6 | 2017-06-25 |2017-06-26 22:05:31 |
|         7 | 2017-06-26 |2017-06-26 22:05:35 |
|         8 | 2017-06-27 |2017-06-26 22:05:40 |
+-----------+------------+------------+-------+
```

Rooms Table

```
+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
| id        |  name      | status     | created_at         |
+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
|         1 | Room A     | 1          |2017-06-26 22:16:21 |
|         2 | Room B     | 1          |2017-06-26 22:21:45 |
+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
```

Slots Table

```
+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
| id        | start_time | end_time   | created_at         | 
+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
|     1     | 07:00 AM   | 08:00 AM   |2017-06-26 20:22:45 |   
|     2     | 08:00 AM   | 09:00 AM   |2017-06-26 20:28:08 |   
|     3     | 09:00 AM   | 10:00 AM   |2017-06-26 20:36:27 |   
|     4     | 10:00 AM   | 11:00 AM   |2017-06-26 20:44:12 |   
+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
```

Bookings Table

```
+-----------+------------+------------+--------+-------------------------+
| id        | room_id    | slot_id    |booked_date  | created_at         |
+-----------+------------+------------+--------+-------------------------+
|1          | 1          | 1          |7            |2017-06-26 22:16:08 |
|2          | 1          | 2          |7            |2017-06-26 22:18:26 |
|3          | 1          | 3          |7            |2017-06-27 05:17:35 |
|4          | 1          | 4          |7            |2017-06-27 06:43:04 |
|5          | 1          | 1          |7            |2017-06-27 08:22:48 |
+-----------+------------+------------+--------+-------------------------+
```

I want to get booking data for a certain room within a range of one week as follows:

Booking Data for Room A:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|date       |07:00-08:00|08:00-09:00|09:00-10:00|10:00-11:00|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|2017-06-26 | Booked    | Booked    | Booked    | Booked    |
|2017-06-27 | Booked    |Not Booked |Not Booked |Not Booked |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Am using the following query but it is not giving me the correct data:

```
SELECT tbl_days.id,tbl_days.date_day,
IF(tbl_bookings.slot_id =1,'Booked','Available') AS '07:00 to 08:00',  
IF(tbl_bookings.slot_id =2,'Booked','Available') AS '08:00 to 09:00',  
IF(tbl_bookings.slot_id =3,'Booked','Available') AS '09:00 to 10:00',  
IF(tbl_bookings.slot_id =4,'Booked','Available') AS '10:00 to 11:00',  
FROM tbl_days,
LEFT JOIN tbl_bookings ON tbl_bookings.booking_date = tbl_days.id,
LEFT JOIN tbl_slots ON tbl_slots.id = tbl_bookings.slot_id,
LEFT JOIN tbl_fields ON tbl_rooms.id = tbl_bookings.room_id
```

However, this is not giving me the intended data.
Will appreciate tips on what I am doing wrong and could do right.

Comment: This is a very common question on SO have you tried googling?

Comment: When using a PIVOT, the MAX(CASE WHEN...END) pattern is common, but I'd always handle the issues around data display in application code, if that's available.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, couldn't get relevant help which is specific to my issue.

Comment: @Strawberry that's feasible, I just need a hack around getting the query right first.

Comment: So, the only query you really need is `SELECT * FROM bookings`. Everything else can be handled in application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a point out from the comment section on using MAX (CASE WHEN.. END)

Finally got a hook of it:

```
SELECT tbl_days.id,tbl_days.date_day,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tbl_bookings.slot_id =1 THEN 'Booked' ELSE 'Available' END) '07:00 to 08:00',  
       MAX(CASE WHEN tbl_bookings.slot_id =2 THEN 'Booked' ELSE 'Available' END) '08:00 to 09:00',  
       MAX(CASE WHEN tbl_bookings.slot_id =3 THEN 'Booked' ELSE 'Available' END) '09:00 to 10:00',  
       MAX(CASE WHEN tbl_bookings.slot_id =4 THEN 'Booked' ELSE 'Available' END) '10:00 to 11:00'  
FROM tbl_days
LEFT JOIN tbl_bookings 
     ON tbl_bookings.day_date = tbl_days.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_slots 
     ON tbl_slots.id = tbl_bookings.slot_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_rooms 
     ON tbl_rooms.id = tbl_bookings.room_id
GROUP BY tbl_days.id;
```